# Errors with gcc when compiling C program

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have a custom shell program in which I have included `signal.h`, `unistd.h`, and `stdio.h`.  I was originally working on this in RedHat Enterprise (not sure exactly what version, but not too old) and I was able to use gcc on my program and it compiled fine and ran fine.  Now I moved it over to Ubuntu and gcc is giving me some errors, the first of which is `conflicting types for 'getline()'`.  Some other errors say `incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function strlen`.  I have overridden the functions in question, why was this working in RedHat but not in Ubuntu?  Linux is not my thing so please speak plainly.  Let me know if you need more error details.

```
/* define a global input buffer */
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXARG 512
#define MAXBUF 512
#define BUFFER_SIZE 50
#define MAX_COMMANDS 10
char buffer [BUFFER_SIZE];
static char *prompt = "MYSHELL>";
static char inpbuf[MAXBUF];
static char *arg[MAXARG+1];
static char tokbuf[2*MAXBUF];
static char *tok = tokbuf;
char history[MAX_COMMANDS][MAXBUF];
int cmd_num;

void getline(void);

void getline() {
int length;

length = read(0, inpbuf, MAXBUF);
if (length == 0) {
    printf("\n");
    exit(0);
}
inpbuf[length] = '\0';

}

void processline() {
char *ptr = inpbuf;
int narg;
for (narg=0;;) {    
    arg[narg] = tok;
    for (; *ptr == ' ' || *ptr == '\t'; ptr++)
        ;
    while(*ptr != ' ' && *ptr != '\t' && *ptr != '\n' && 
          *ptr != '\0' && *ptr != ';' && *ptr != '&') 
        *tok++ = *ptr++;
    *tok++ = '\0';
    if (narg < MAXARG)
        narg++;
    if (*ptr == '\n')
        break;
}
// clear the input buffer
for (ptr = inpbuf; *ptr != '\n'; ptr++)
    *ptr = ' ';
if (narg != 0) {
    arg[narg] = NULL;
}
}

void handle_SIGINT()
{
write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, strlen(buffer));
}

int main()
{
    int pid, exitstat, ret;
    struct sigaction handler;
    handler.sa_handler = handle_SIGINT;
    handler.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&handler.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGINT, &handler, NULL);
    strcpy(buffer, "Caught Control C\n");

    while (1) {
        printf("%s ", prompt);
        fflush(stdout);
        getline();
        processline();
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "myshell: error\n");
            return (-1);
        }

        if (pid == 0) {
            execvp(*arg, arg);
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", *arg);
            exit(127);
        }
        waitpid(pid, &exitstat, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161012/what-does-error-conflicting-types-for-mean. I think @brice answers your question.

Comment: It would be most helpful for you to try to reduce the program down to a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. Keep on removing all of your code until you have just the includes and declarations (and maybe a "hello, world") that demonstrates the problem. This may help you find the problem, but if it does not, you can edit your question and post it here which will help us to be able to find your problem.

Comment: Header file contents can vary from system to system and compiler build to compiler build and across libraries. You may find the output of `gcc -E` highly illuminating. And what Brian Campbell said.

Comment: Yes, obviously what Brain said, but I am trying to avoid "removing" code to find the problem.  This has worked on another system and even though I realize that compilers vary from system to system, I was hoping this was something simple that someone could answer right off the top of their head.

Comment: Ah, the old "Please don't make me do any work to solve my problem" defense. This was tried in the Tarrasch - Lasker match of 1908, but was easily countered by the Chicago Gambit. May you have better luck with it.

Comment: @msw I (as well as most people) could solve just about any problem if enough time was applied.  There comes a point where you ask for help for the sake of efficiency.  I have no problem with work.

Comment: Allow me to be more blunt: You've now spent more time justifying your failure to give others the information they need to figure out your trouble than it would have taken to provide the information.

Comment: @msw what information have I not given?  Additionally I have not failed, I just have not succeeded yet.  As a matter of fact I am working on this program right now (under RedHat).

Comment: @typoknig:  Not to mention, you've caused other people positive work trying to get you to conform to community norms.  This is not a paid help line.  If you want to get help, you're better off meeting us halfway.

Comment: @David Thornley you and msw are basically saying I am not giving you enough info correct? What info have you asked for that I have not provided?  Help me help you help me!

Comment: @msw You should ask me if this is homework instead of just adding a tag.  This WAS homework for me at one time, but that assignment is already done.  I am working on this of my own accord.

Comment: @typoknig:  You were asked to provide a smaller example of what went wrong.  You didn't.  It's not a question of providing information, but of providing easily accessible information.  It's almost always easier for the questioner to cut down on the size of the code sample than for the answerer to figure out what's important.

Comment: @David Thornley, I thought the code I provided was small enough, I cut the entire command history section out.  I will try to remove some more stuff to make it easier to diagnosis.  As this is not an urgent matter for me it may be a couple of days before I get back to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest solution would be to rename your `getline()` function, e.g. to `my_getline()`

Comment: This did get rid of most of my errors, but I wonder why `gcc` on RedHat allowed me to override those functions but `gcc` on Ubuntu did not...  Seems strange to me.

Answer (score 4):

`incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function strlen`

Include [`<string.h>`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/string.h.html)

`conflicting types for 'getline()`

`<stdio.h>` already contains a declaration of getline, so make sure that nowhere in your code you have redeclared/redefined `getline()`[with a different prototype].

Comment: I did have a prototype (per ANSI C) for getline, and several other functions (that are declared in `stdio.h`).  What I don't get though is why this worked in RedHat exactly as I have it now, but not in Ubuntu.  I am posting the code.

Comment: @typoknig:  If you've made an error, such as using `strlen` without providing a suitable prototype, the compiler may not be under any obligation to warn you.  If you invoke undefined behavior, the standard allows anything to happen, including what you actually expect.  It's rarely worthwhile analyzing why a faulty program worked on a particular system.

Answer (score 0):

```
gcc -Wall typoknig.c
typoknig.c:19: error: conflicting types for ‘getline’
//usr/include/stdio.h:671: note: previous declaration of ‘getline’ was here
typoknig.c:21: error: conflicting types for ‘getline’
//usr/include/stdio.h:671: note: previous declaration of ‘getline’ was here
```

Two separate declarations of `getline` which Andy had recommended that you use `my_getline()` since the former is already part of `stdio.h`.

> typoknig.c: In function ‘getline’:
>   typoknig.c:27: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘exit’
>   typoknig.c:27: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’

That can't be good, `man exit` says right at the top:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void exit(int status);
```

perhaps you need to include `stdlib.h`? What does gcc assume is the signature of an undeclared function?

> typoknig.c: In function ‘handle_SIGINT’:
>   typoknig.c:59: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strlen’
>   typoknig.c:59: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’

Ouch, `man strlen` to the rescue:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Fortunately, `string.h` will help out with the next one and we already nailed `exit`:

> typoknig.c: In function ‘main’:
>   typoknig.c:70: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcpy’
>   typoknig.c:70: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strcpy’
>   typoknig.c:85: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’

Ain't that pre-processor nifty?

```
typoknig.c:87: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘waitpid’
typoknig.c:64: warning: unused variable ‘ret’
```

Sayeth `man waitpid`:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

Line 64 is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: That it compiled at all under any gcc is the true puzzle.

Comment: look I appreciate your help, but maybe you missed the "speak plainly" part of my question.  I get what you are saying in some parts of your answer, but not all.  I get the jest of what you and David are saying (which I already knew) that I have functions declared twice. It just does not seem like there should be such a huge difference between the two systems I am working on, and I have a hard time grasping why it works with no errors in RedHat but has lots of errors in Ubuntu.  This is just a side project so I am not deeply concerned about it, I was just curious to know the "why".

Answer (score 0):

`Getline()` is not part of C standard. It is a GNU extension. In c++ `Getline()` is standard.

So adding to your code right before your #includes

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

should fix the warning. Also see "man getline" on linux.